# Working with option in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a few `Option` objects, say a, b and c. I want to concatenate their values if they are not `None` like this:

```
var str = "values: "
if (!a.isEmpty) str = str + a.get
if (!b.isEmpty) str = str + b.get
if (!c.isEmpty) str = str + c.get
```

This is very imperative and javaish. Is there a better way to do this with Scala and still
keep the code readable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This question calls for some obligatory scalaz answers:

import scalaz:

```
scala> import scalaz._ ; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

create some optional values:

```
scala> val List(a,b,c,d) = List(Some("str1"), Some("str2"),None,Some("str3"))
a: Option[String] = Some(str1)
b: Option[String] = Some(str2)
c: Option[String] = None
d: Option[String] = Some(str3)
```

scalaz creates a unary ~ operator for Option[A] where A has a monoid, such that ~a is the same as `a.getOrElse(Monoid[A].zero)`, for the string monoid, the zero element is an empty string (`""`)

```
scala> "values: " + ~a + ~b + ~c + ~d
res0: String = values: str1str2str3
```

`|+|` is syntax for the monoid append operation, Option[A] has a monoid when A has a monoid, so this. This allows us to append `Option[String]`s together to get a new `Option[String]`

```
scala> "values: " +  (a |+| b |+| c |+| d).getOrElse("")
res1: String = values: str1str2str3
```

combining both operators:

```
scala> "values: " +  ~(a |+| b |+| c |+| d)
res2: String = values: str1str2str3
```

Answer (score 4):

Putting Options in a collection (List) enables to perform operations on all elements (Options), in this case flatten does the job to take value out of Options, mkString is merging list of strings.

```
List(Some("str1"), Some("str2"),None,Some("str3")).flatten.mkString
```

Comment: @Baku - Please don't edit answers of other users. Rolled back edit to original.

Comment: Heh, other commenter reminds us, `vs.flatten.mkString("values: ", "", "")`

Comment: -1. If you can't spare a minute to add some context you probably shouldn't be answering questions on Stack Overflow—this isn't a race. A single line of code might work for the OP, but he or she isn't the only person who will read this.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 99 ways to do this in Scala. Given xs is list of options,
pick your poison.

```
 "Values:  " + (for{Some(s) <- xs} yield s).mkString
```

or

```
   xs.foldLeft("Values: ")( _ + _.getOrElse(""))
```

not to mention flatten and flatMap

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "values: " + a.getOrElse("") + b.getOrElse("") + c.getOrElse("")
```

If this is insufficiently functional looking:

```
var str = "values: " + List(a, b, c).map {_.getOrElse("")}.mkString
```

Answer (score -2):

```
val str = List(a, b,c).flatten.mkString(",")
```

Comment: OP doesn't want commas.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg OP wants header, so `vs.flatten.mkString("values: ", "", "")`